# Problem with Printing Integers from Sorted Set in Scala

Tags: scala

To begin, I am a beginner in Scala and have been using this language for a matter of days. For a class I am attempting to print a sorted set of integers to the console, but for some reason they keep printing with a "D" on the end of the first single-digit integer on the first print loop.

```scala
def getInputNumbers: (Boolean, SortedSet[Int]) {
  var setOfInts: SortedSet[Int] = SortedSet()
    var repeats = false
    var input = readLine()

    while(input != null) {
      try {
        val intInput = input.toInt
        if(setOfInts.contains(intInput)) repeats = true
        else setOfInts = setOfInts + intInput
      } catch {
        case e : java.lang.NumberFormatException => {
          println("ERROR")

          // Kill the program if there's an error with the input
          sys.exit(0)
        }
      }
      input = readLine()
    }
    (repeats, setOfInts)
}

val results = getInputNumbers
results._2.foreach(println(_))
if(results._1) println("REPEATS") else println("NO REPEATS")
```

Assuming the sorted set contains `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, the following is the output:

```
1D
2
3
4
```

But when the sorted set contains `{10, 11, 12}`, the following is the output:

```
10
11
12
```

as wanted.

Another interesting thing that happens is that when changing the code to the following:

```scala
def getInputNumbers(): (Boolean, SortedSet[Integer]) { ... }

val results = getInputNumbers
results._2.foreach(println(_))
results._2.foreach(println(_))
```

and the sorted set contains `{1, 2, 3, 4}` the following is the output:

```
1D
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

which is not consistent with the original print statement.

It appears that the `println()` function is converting the first integer to a double, but this may not be the case. I have searched all over the internet as well and cannot find any discussions regarding this issue. Any ideas on how to get this to work as intended?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in `2.12` nor in `2.13`. Please share your full code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the Java `Integer` instead of the Scala `Int`?

Comment: One other minor point: by convention, a function that is declared with no arguments, but with empty parentheses, has _side-effects_ (that is, it does something other than just return a value). If the function has no side-effects, then it should be declared without the parentheses. But however you define it, you should be consistent when calling it; if the definition has parentheses, they should be used when calling it; if the definition has no parentheses, neither should calls to that function. You declare `getInputNumbers` _with_ parentheses, but call it without them.

Comment: Maybe ctl-D `^D` is overwritten by the first line.

Comment: Just edited with the full code and some changes as suggested. This code still produces the same problems.

Comment: @Ian so it seems that like som-snytt predicted the _"problem"_ is in your terminal. That `D` that you see is the cone from `CTRL + D` that you probably use to finish the input of numbers.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, why does it only occur with single digit integers? Why not with 2 digit integers or any other input?

Comment: @Ian it is not that it occurs with a single, it occurs with the first. Try printing anything before.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ah, I see it now! When running on a different machine, everything printed as expected...interesting issue that I haven't had happen with any other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was an issue with how things were being printed. My console was printing `^D` when typing Ctrl-D to indicate EOF. When running on a different machine, everything worked as expected.